# .htaccess redirecting URL to a folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with Apache .htaccess
I want to redirect `www.abc.com.au/folder1/folder2/file.php?pi=xyz` to look like:
`www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/folder 2/`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(folder1)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$3/file.php?pi=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Worked good but it causing another problem.
 if I create another folder e.g. www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/
www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/folder 2/ wont work need to overide the root file i.e. put another file at www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/ (folder xyz). 
what to do??? any help is appriciated

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: it is working  for the path www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/folder2/ good except for the path www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/  is not working i.e www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/  loading with errors. I have files at the folder www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/ xyz is index.php file I have links to www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/ . the script is working for www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/folder 2/ but I cannot have files in  www.abc.com.au/folder1/   e.g. www.abc.com.au/folder1/index.php

Comment: All worked I just needed to change the directory name from www.abc.com.au/folder1/xyz/index.php to capital directory e.g. www.abc.com.au/folder1/XYZ/index.php

Comment: Great to know it worked. Sorry I could not respond as I was traveling today.